Prevent BillboardGui text scaling
I have a BillboardGUi in my tycoon game and it has a Frame and a TextLabel in it. The TextLabel displays what this object is and how much does it cost. (It is part of the button that buys things...)
So on my BillboardGui I have Max distance on and set to 40.
Basically, when I go back, the text gets bigger and some parts disappear (They go off the frame) and when I get close, the text become so small.
Far away...

Close up...

How can I fix it? I want it not to scale and not to get out of frame how do I do that?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
